# What does this code mean? $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

i know this:

```
$.getJSON(
  "test.js",
  function(json){
    alert("JSON Data:   " + json.users[3].name);
  }
);
```

but i see the code in a site:

```
$.getJSON(l, {
                                tag: "userName",
                                userName: 'sss'
                            }
```

what is '1' mean,in this place.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you copy/pasted, then that's actually an "L", not a one. "`l`" is probably a variable containing a URL/filename.

Comment: Nice catch. This confusion seems to be just about bad formatting. I see nothing wrong with the code, really. - *(This is why we don't use single letters as variable names. Programmers != mathematicians! :D)*

Answer (score 0):

That actually might be a variable:

```
$(function(){
  var l = "getJSON.php";
  $.getJSON(l, { 'data':'foo' }, function(data) {
    alert(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: But if the user is on an HTML page, why is it getting the same page as JSON?

Answer (score 0):

...quite honestly, it looks like bad code. According to the [jQuery API browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), argument one should be a URL, not a number. Does the code sample function?

**EDIT**: Just checked; it does not. That code sample does nothing.

Comment: Note that the OP doesn't actually post the closing `)` of the function call, so as far as we know, there may well be a callback that the OP left out. *(I doubt it, but since he's leaving stuff out...)*

Answer (score 0):

The first argument is an `l` (as in letter), not a `1` (as in 1 font you should probably avoid), and is a URL.

The second argument is an object containing data to be sent with the request.

`jQuery.ajax()` defaults to a `GET` request, so that data will be parameterized and added to the URL as `tag=userName&userName=sss`

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/